# Not getting expected value returning from public method of another Form. Though working fine in the same class or when returning a specific value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two Forms. Form5 and Form6. In Form5 there is a public method SelectedEvent(). When i create an object variable of Form5 then it doesn't return the proper value. When i call the method from another method of Form5(same class) it works. Now another wired thing is- when i assigned a specific value to be returned inside that method, then it can be fetch from inside Form6! The codes will explain more i hope-

(I'm writing only the necessary components from the whole project.)

```
public partial class Form5 : Form
{
`\\there are many other methods too`

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=FinalLabDairy;Integrated Security=True");
        int x;
        public Form5()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

         public int SelectedEvent()
        {
            return this.x;
        }

`\\the method where i assigned the value of 'x':`
        private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.x = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["EID"].Value.ToString());
        }

`\\I'm sure the value has been assigned correctly because it works in the method below:`
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"DELETE FROM [dbo].[Events] WHERE EID='"+SelectedEvent()+"'", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            int x = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(x);
        }

}
```

Now in Form6 class-

```
public partial class Form6 : Form
{
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form5 f = new Form5();            
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE [dbo].[Events] SET [Date] = '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "',[Time] = '" + dateTimePicker2.Text + "',[Title] = '" + txttitle.Text + "',[Description] = '" + txtdesc.Text + "',[Priority] = '" + comboBox1.Text + "',[LastMod] = '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "'WHERE EID='"+ f.SelectedEvent() +"'", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
`\\i put this MessageBox just to see if the value of 'x' coming through correctly`
            MessageBox.Show(f.SelectedEvent().ToString());
        }
}
```

And now unfortunately f.SelectedEvent() is not returning the correct value. Instead it's returning '0'.

The funny thing is when i changed the return value in SelectedEvent() method like below-

```
public int SelectedEvent()
        {
            this.x = 1001;
            return this.x;
        }
```

It works like a charm. I mean the value 1001 is returning inside the Form6 where f.SelectedEvent() is called! So it seems like the problem occurs only when the method is calling from another Form and the value of x is assigned outside of the method!

I don't know why it's not returning the assigned value of x instead of 0! Moreover, how can it returns the specified value assigned in the method but returning 0 when it is assigned from another method? 
Note: When assigned from another method it works in the same form, so we can sort out the possibility of x is not getting assigned properly. Also i tried with making 'x' and the method used for assigning as 'Public', that doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both answers were helpful. Specially the one from @nvoigt. The answers made me realize the main problem was to creating a new instance of the form(with the "new" keyword); where the desired method was located. So basically the solution was to create a reference to call that method, hence getting the existing desired value. I tried several ways to do that but in the end this following method successfully worked for me-

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form object_name = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Form_Name"];
```

Then retrieve the existing value from the method by-

```
(Form_Name)object_name).method_name();
```

To be more clear & specific, if i consider the two form's above in the question-

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form f = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Form5"];
```

And then calling the method-

```
(Form5)f).SelectedEvent();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Form5 f = new Form5();
```

You have created a completely **new** Form5 and somehow expect it to hold the value of the *already existing, other* Form5. That's like buying a new IKEA cabinet of the same make as your other one and then being surprised that your books aren't in the new one. No. the books are still in the old one.

Another example:

```
int x = 5;
int y = new int();
```

Would you be surprised to hear that y is **not** 5? Probably not. This is not a new concept, you already knew this.

To get the value of your *existing* Form5, you will need to get a reference to it and then call the function *on that reference*. Not on a new one. Without more code it's difficult to say, but at some point you open a Form5 instance, if it's a modal dialog, right after closing it would be the point to grab that value. If it's not a modal dialog, you need to pass the instance of Form5 that is opened to a method of your Form6 as a parameter so you can save it for later use.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking about this if creating a new form is the problem. Let me try to solve it with a reference. But can you please elaborate what you mean by "...if it's a modal dialog, right after closing it would be the point to grab that value."? Thanx a lot.

Comment: Well, if you open a Form5 and the user selects something and clicks "OK" then after your call to ShowDialog you can call your function and get the value. No need for Form6 to ever know about Form5 if you can just pass that value around.

Comment: Btw, another silly question about your original answer: i understood clearly now how a new Form5 is  returning null value. But what about when i assigned 'x' in the that method-
public int SelectedEvent()
        {
            this.x = 1001;
            return this.x;
        }

Wouldn't it also suppose to return null value instead of '1001'? Or am i wrong? I mean, when i'm assigning like the above code, it's returning '1001'!

Comment: Sure, that code will be called, it's in the method. You can put a breakpoint and use the debugger to see what happens.

Comment: Thanx a lot! Let me solve the problem and get back to you. Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 2):

In `button1_Click` you are not showing `f` to the user anywhere. You seem to be missing `f.Show()`. How do you expect to have a selected index if the form hasn't been activated at all, the user cant see it and make the event handler `Form5.dataGridView1_CellMouseClick` run by clicking on `dataGridview1`?

Your first problem is that `Form5.dataGridView1_CellMouseClick` is never called and therefore `x` is never assigned. Your second problem is that query inside `button1_Click1` should not run *until* the user selects something in `dataGridView1`, and you are not waiting for that to happen, so it will run regardless if the user has selected something or not. That query should run only when `Form5.dataGridView1` raises the appropiate event. Becuase you need to execute the query inside `Form6`, the way to go is the following:

1. Make a public custom event in `Form5` that is raised everytime the appropiate `Form5.dataGridView1` event is raised.
2. Subscribe `Form6` to that event
3. Run the query inside the event handler in `Form6` that handles the public custom event exposed in `Form5`.

And finally, I'm not sure you are subscribing to the best event in `dataGridView1`. Wouldn't something like `SelectionChanged` or `RowEnter`  be a better option?

On another topic, please, start getting into the habit of calling objects with reasonable and understandable names. `Form5`, `Form6`, `dataGridView1`, etc. is just a great recipee for future headaches (for you or for the poor guy who inherits your code in the future).

Comment: The form has been activated. I didn't write the full code as i thought it wasn't relative. Also dataGridView1 was called and x was assigned. I even tested it. Sorry for the misrepresentation. I'm new here.

I will try to remember your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: @Ishmamshahir Read my edit, and please get into the habit of posting complete code of relevant methods, because your assumption of what is relevant and what is not is probably wrong; if you knew perfectly well what is and what is not relevant, you'd have probably found the solution to your problem already!

Comment: I am posting the Form5 code assuming that people would understand form5 is showing already and after i selected from dataGridView1, then the value has been assigned. Hence i didn't wrote where it was activated.

So, by relative information you want me to write another Form which has a method where i activated my form5? In that case you would probably ask me to write the full code which activated the form that activated Form5 and so on!?

Well, thank you for your answer and sorry that my post was vague for you.

Comment: @Ishmamshahir No, where did you get the idea that you need a third form? Your desired order of events is: user opens `Form5` clicking on appropiate button in `Form6` -> user selects row in `Form5` -> `Form6` executes non query. The current order of execution in thecode you've shown is not that.

Comment: @Ishmamshahir You code is doing: user opens `Form5` clicking on appropiate button in `Form6` -> `Form6` executes non query. *When* the user selects a row in `Form5` can happen at any moment, and unless the user is blindingly fast (I'm talking miliseconds here), the non query will be executed *before* the user has time to select anything in `Form5`'s `dataGridView1`.

Comment: @Ishmamshahir What you need is a way to inform `Form6` when the user has selected something in `Form5`'s `dataGridView1` because thats the only time when you should be running the non query. You've got two options: make `dataGridView1` public and subcribe `Form6` to its appropiate event (I don't like it) or implement a custom public event in `Form5` that signals when its `dataGridView1` selection has changed and subcribe `Form6` to *that* event. The non query should then execute inside the handler of *that* event.

Comment: Ohh ok, may be i got the confusion now. Actually in my code, Form5 was opened from another Form. Then when dataGridView1 is selected and another button is clicked, it opens the Form6. Where i'm editing the info of the dataGridView1 thus in the database. So in the second Form (Form6), when i click button1 it was suppose to just call the public method where i stored the specific Row Index and use it in the query. It means the Form5 was opened and the dataGridView1 was selected in the first place then we go to Form6 by clicking a button. Was this helpful?

Comment: @Ishmamshahir and also, rereading your last comments, I'm not sure if you are understanding what `Form5` you are showing. You do realize that inside `Form6.button1_Click` you are newing up a *new* `Form6` referenced in the *local* variable `f` and that one is not being activated inside the method? If you are expecting `f.x` to be a given value, it doesn't matter how many other `Form6` you might be showing with a valid selection, `f` isn't shown and `f.x` will therefore always be `0`, which brings us back to square 1.

Comment: yaahhh. And see the other answer. So far it seems like the problem is i have created a new Form6 named f which is neither activated nor contains the value of previously assigned 'x'. You are correct about this, i actually didn't realize this. :D

Comment: @Ishmamshahir no problem, glad to help.